# React-router conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

Is it alright to make conditional rendering inside of `render` function of `<Route />` component of React-router? Kind of this:

```
<Route exact path="/form" render={props => (
  this.props.dataLoaded && <Form {...props} />
)} />
```

The idea is ... I **dont want to mount the `Form` component** until some data in parent component are loaded.

I have that data in redux store, so basically I could access it inside of the child component. The problem is that I would have to check the changes and make some additional stuff in order to achieve what I need.

The conditional rendering seems to me as much simpler solution.
I just havent seen it anywhere yet so Im not sure whether it is technically right solution.

Comment: You could do it this way or you could create a parent component that controls the logic and conditionally rends <Form>. Then link the parent component to the route.

Comment: From a technical point of view, you can use such an approach. Please make sure that it's ok from the user perspective - you could use some loading state for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solutions for you and you can choose.
first, you can render some component if data loaded otherwise you can load for example some other like loading component

```
<Route exact path="/form" render={props => (
     this.props.dataLoaded === true? <Form {...props} /> : <Loading {...props}/>
)} />
```

so if `dataLoaded` is equal to `true` it renders `<Form>` otherwise render `<Loading>`.
Another solution is completely rendered router if data loaded:

```
{this.props.dataLoaded && <Route exact path="/form" render={props => <Form {...props}/>} /> }
```

in this scenario `<Form>` is accessible only if `dataLoaded` is true